# Including libraries in a package or main Script

Tags: r, package

I am building a package for the first time.

The package needs couple of libraries to work. Should I include those libraries in the package for every function? or should I include them in my main Script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the DESCRIPTION file in your package you can list the packages your package depends on. This will allow you to use the code from those packages to be used anywhere in your package. So, there is no need for explicit use of `library` or `require`. When your package is loaded, the other packages will also be loaded. In addition, when setting `dependencies = TRUE` in `install.packages` the packages your package depends on will also be installed (if available on CRAN).

Comment: Do you mean this: `Depends: Data.table, Plyr`, if the package is **mypackage** , should I only use `library(mypackage)` in my main script?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The packages your package depends on will be loaded automatically.